# Telegraf and Cloud Functions: How to stop Telegram Bot from receiving endless old update

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-functions, telegram-bot, telegraf

I have written a simple Telegram bot using the Telegraf framework and have it deployed to Firebase Cloud Function, and all is well until one evening there was an error, and the bot simply stopped responding. After doing some debugging, I redeployed back up to Cloud Functions and a whole series of old messages just keeps flooding the chat.

I have read that it has something to do with getUpdates, and that I need to send a response 200 when the message has been successfully sent. This has always been in place but somehow it does't work.

Here is my implementation:

```
//at functions/index.js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const bot = require('./bot')

exports.start = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    return bot.handleUpdate(req.body, res)
    .then(() => {
        res.status(200).send();
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log('Function start err', err)
    })
})

// at bot.js
const Telegraf = require('telegraf')
const constants = require('./constants')
const token = constants.telegramBotToken
const bot = new Telegraf(token)

let commands = [
    require('./commands/start'),
    require('./commands/settings'),
    //and a few more commands
]

commands.map((command) => {
    return command(bot)
})

bot.launch()
module.exports = bot

//An example at command code, ie at /commands/start
module.exports = (bot) => bot.start((ctx) => {
    let msg = ctx.message
    let userFirstName = msg.from.first_name
    let startMessage = `
    <b>Hello ${userFirstName}!</b> blahblah`
    var option = {
        "parse_mode": "HTML",
    }

    ctx.reply(startMessage)
    .catch((err) => {
       console.log('/start error', err)
    })
})
```

I follow this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hZwZO9EeZ3k&list=PLhMX5hA0NWUQoRqYNFBE35NlUn1J915M0&index=11&t=0s) on the deployment, have tried the following but all doesn't resolve:

1. Removing the webhook
2. Deleting the start cloud function and redeploying again

Answer (score 0):

Your function should send a response to the client in **all** conditions.  Right now, you only send a response when the promise returned from `handleUpdate` indicates success.  You should also send an error response if it fails:

```
.catch((err) => {
    console.log('Function start err', err)
    res.send(500)
})
```

This is just a basic 500 error, but you should send whatever you want.

If your function doesn't send a response, then it will time out after the default 60 seconds.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The thing is that the errors were never caught in this catch block, ie the log statement of `Function start err` were never printed on gcloud console. And peculiarly, I do not see any `Function execution start` or `Function execution ended` logs, but the Bot continues to blast the messages.

Comment: OK, well, it seems that you're not showing the implementation for handleUpdate, so there's not much else I can see that's going on.  I also don't know how the client is making the request, or how it's making a decision to call (or even not call) the function. I've never heard of HTTP functions having the behavior you're describing (and I've spent a lot of time with them), so something else is probably going on.

Comment: the method `handleUpdate` comes from Telegraf framework https://telegraf.js.org/#/?id=handleupdate. and the bot in `index.js` is the bot in `module.exports` in `bot.js`.